# Gradle multi module project - custom task to execute action on a given sub-module

Tags: java, gradle

I have a multi-module gradle project with the following structure:

```
root_project
----sub-moduleA
--------build.gradle
----sub-moduleB
--------buld.gradle
----build.gradle
----settings.gradle
```

I would like to create a custom task on the 'build.gradle' file on the 'root_project' that allows me to execute a given action (lets say 'test') just on a given sub-module.

I know that I can do this from the command line, lets say execute the 'test' task on 'sub-moduleA':

```
gradle :sub-moduleA:test
```

Is it possible to create a custom task on the root_project build.gradle file to do this action?

Comment: You *could*, but I'm wondering if you're just adding a layer of indirection to what is already a fairly straightforward (and IDE-friendly) approach.

Comment: Makoto, what could be that approach? Perhaps I'm missing something obvious. I'm using Intellij.

Comment: My team has used multi-modules for several projects and has had no issues with the extra step of adding the submodule as a specifier.  IntelliJ's Run Anywhere context will pick up on this and auto-complete any available submodules needed.  I'm curious/concerned that you want to do this to paper over the conventions, but that may result in even more confusing or unmaintainable build scripts.

Comment: All right, I was not aware of the 'RunAnywhere' feature of IntelliJ, I see it is a convenient way of entering the command quickly.